# Go: check whether type of value is function

Tags: reflection, casting, go

How I can check that some variable in golang has type `func`, like this:

```
func A() {}

func main() {
    variable := A
    isFunc := IsFunc(variable) // true or false
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
func IsFunc(v any) bool {
   return reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Func
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Already solved with this:

```
func IsFunc(fn interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.TypeOf(fn).Kind() == reflect.Func
}
```